# How to change image to next one in hbs handlebars, nodejs with multer

Tags: express-handlebars

I am building a classified ads website (like craigslist) with: handlebars (hbs), nodejs and multer for uploading images.

I have already created my own CRUD.

Users could post their ads for free, introducing their info for each ad:

- user name
- email
- ad title
- ad description
- ad city
- ad category
- **ad images (more than one if user needs)**

I have a view, **list.hbs**, where ads show its information:

[image]

When users clicks on ad pictures, it will open like a modal box / pop up:

[image]

Everything perfect until here.

I save pictures in my ad.model, through multer like this:

```
  image: {
      imgName:{
        type:String
      },
      imgPath:{
        type:[String]
      }
  }
```

As you can see, I store path's pictures in an array to my mongodb database (managed by mongoose).

I.e:

```
"image" : {
    "imgPath" : [
        "uploads/e3c97fb10dd4c602054bedce194464b6",
        "uploads/302fe7e147932d2b868a79b1799ba3f9"
    ]
}
```

The problem is here. I 've been trying to change image after clicking in each picture and it is impossible to do it.

I have tried via , but it looks like hbs doesn't work properly and don't read variables from handlebars:

[image]

I even tried passing through helper via onclick = myfunction({{#imageHelper}}{{/imageHelper}}), but it doesn't work...

Anybody knows how to handle this in handlebars? How to add js code to this view?

Note: my modal box / pop up is made it with pure html / css, no js or jquery in there.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe my mistake, how I didn't noticed before!

If you reach this question, or any question linked to handlebars - multer - javascript DOM, please, don't forget that template variables inside an onclick element MUST be quoted.

**Mistake / Error**

I passed through onclick element this:

```
 <img onclick="myFun({{ad.reference}},{{ad.image.imgPath}})" class="imgAd" id="{{ad.reference}}" src="{{ad.image.imgPath.[0]}}"/>
```

And to manage the src and change images clicking everywhere on the image, I tried to do this:

```
...

<script>
  let i = 0;
  //next prev image
  function myFun(ref,str){ 
    const arr = str.split(',');
    const len = arr.length;
    if(i < len - 1){
      i = i + 1;
      document.getElementById(ref).src = arr[i]
    } 
    else {
    i = 0;
    document.getElementById(ref).src = arr[i]
    
    }
  }
</script>
```

(This script above, just for change next picture, and so on)

Remember: if you pass variables like that, not quoted, js will throw errors, because it receives a "variable" like parameter, not a string.

In this case onclick received this:

```
uploads/b5e01da1707382ed915f314c0c77266c //variable, not string
```

Correct way:

```
<img onclick="myFun('{{ad.reference}}','{{ad.image.imgPath}}')" class="imgAd" id="{{ad.reference}}" display="block" src="{{ad.image.imgPath.[0]}}"/>
```

I passed a string, not a variable:

After I quoted each handlebar variable, I passed as string.

```
"uploads/b5e01da1707382ed915f314c0c77266c"
```

Now, the script will works. I get a string that I need to transform in an array to handle it:

```
<script>
  let i = 0;
  //next prev image
  function myFun(ref,str){ 
    const arr = str.split(',');
    const len = arr.length;
    if(i < len - 1){
      i = i + 1;
      document.getElementById(ref).src = arr[i]
    } 
    else {
    i = 0;
    document.getElementById(ref).src = arr[i]
    
    }
  }
</script>
```

With this, I was able to manage DOM in each ad, changing images after clicking with nodejs, hbs and multer.